# TFS Automatically replace all files when I load the project

Tags: tfs

When ever I open a project, all my local files are replaced with TFS server files. And all the local files will have current datestamp. 
For testing I unmaped the project , then all the local files automatically deleted.

I am working of many projects, but this issue is with only this project

Note : Tools > Options > Source Control > Enviornment > 'Get everything when a soulution or project is opend' has default value. ie. unchecked.

TFS Version : 2018, 
Visual Studio Version : 2013

Comment: Only guessing? Look in the csproj file in Notepad for 4 `Scc*` tags in the XML - if they are not `SAK` try changing them to that. If not, try removing and re-applying the source control binding in the SLN file?